# MSMQ Listeners using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

Do anybody knows how to implement **MSMQ Listeners** **using WCF** ?

i have 2 wcf services built, 1 for sending data to MSMQ queue and another is called by MSMQ listener when there is an insertion in MSMQ queue.Now i wanna know how and where i need to write this MSMQ listener.

Comment: So much information on SO about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372935/wcf-and-msmq
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154853/msmq-and-wcf-service
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526958/msmq-wcf-and-flaky-servers

Comment: i have 2 wcf services built, 1 for sending data to MSMQ queue and another is called by MSMQ listener when there is an insertion in MSMQ queue.Now i wanna know how and where i need to write this MSMQ listener.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to manually implement a queue listener on your service.

Simply by creating your service operation contract you are specifying the handler method which will be called when a message arrives on the local queue.

You probably (or should) have something like this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
void HandleMyMessage (MsmqMessage<String> message);
```

This will ensure that the method HandleMyMessage() in your service implementation will be called when a message is delivered.

**UPDATE**

In response to your question in the comment below, to define the queue address you can do this in the `<System.ServiceModel>` configuration:

```
<services>
  <service 
      name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.OrderProcessorService"
      behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Define NetMsmqEndpoint -->
    <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/ServiceModelSamplesTransacted"
              binding="netMsmqBinding"
              contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.IOrderProcessor" />
    <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789032.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot hugh. So you mean to say only one service fulfills both send and receive operations right?

Comment: Where do you specify queuename, to which i need to listen?